# iOS: What should I use EST or EDT and why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, timezone

I asked a question not too long ago about timezone and I was using EST. Users suggested me to use EDT. I want to know why I should use one or the other because they both print the same time for me. Here is the code to better illustrate what I mean.

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *edtDf = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[edtDf setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"EDT"]];
[edtDf setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

NSString *stringDate = [edtDf stringFromDate:today];

NSLog(@"The EDT is %@", stringDate);

NSDate *today1 = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *estDf = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[estDf setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"EST"]];
[estDf setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

NSString *stringDate1 = [estDf stringFromDate:today1];

NSLog(@"The EST is %@", stringDate1);
```

Comment: The better question is why are you setting the timezone at all? By the default, the user's current timezone is used. Why do you specifically want Eastern (Standard or Daylight) time?

Comment: And, as mentioned in the answer you accepted, you need to use `timeZoneWithAbbreviation`, not `timeZoneWithName:` for both timezone values.

Comment: My fault. I changed it to abbreviation. But the reason being is because the server I am working with needs EST / EDF  specifically. However, they display the same time still

Comment: Is this "server" a web service? If so, your server team should change that interface. One generally designs web services to use ISO 8601/RFC 3339 date strings that include time zone information (a common format is 2015-03-10T01:46:00Z). You really don't want your server sending (or otherwise requiring) some local time zone (at the very least, without including time zone information in the string itself).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They may print different things depending on the time of year (since time of year determines whether Daylight Saving Time is active).

Don't use `EST` **or** `EDT`. Use `US/Eastern` or `America/New_York`:

```
NSTimeZone *tz = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"US/Eastern"];
// or
NSTimeZone *tz = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/New_York"];
```

These time zones adjust for Daylight Saving Time at the correct times of the year.